# Checkboxes in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, checkbox, xamarin.forms

I’m trying to make a page in my app where a user selects from a list of choices, then presses done to submit what he has selected. I’m using Xamarin.Forms. I directly thought of using checkboxes to achieve this; but apparently Xamarin.Forms doesn’t have checkboxes . Anyone have any suggestions to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/kirtisagar/XamarinFormsRadioButtonXAML check this

Comment: The user should be able to select more than one radio; can I do that with this?

Comment: The sample has implemented Radio Group(more than one radio) @MullerA

Comment: Ok that’s great. Thank you!

Comment: sorry i have some misunderstandings. what you need is checkbox not radio button

Comment: Yes; a checkbox to select multiple options. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you don't seem to be looking for a radiobutton but more for something like a checkbox.

I've used this package: https://github.com/messier16/Forms.Controls to use checkboxes

> Make sure to call Messier16Controls.InitAll(); right after Xamarin.Forms.Init(); in your projects. Look a tht AppDelegate.cs code snippet from the sample app:

```
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    Messier16Controls.InitAll();
```

Comment: Thanks, but since I'm quite a beginner with Visual Studio and GitHub; might you instruct me as to how to get around this installation?

Comment: Open your package manager prompt and type this: Install-Package Messier16.Forms.Controls -Version 0.5.1 Afterwards follow the instructions on the github ( with hadding the inits(). Than u can just link it to your xaml page and you good to go. If you don't understand it tell me, and i'll extend my answer tommorow

Comment: Thanks so much! Package manager meaning the NuGet package manager? And is the link that I should put on my XAML provided on GitHub? Thanks!

Comment: Check this example page: https://github.com/messier16/Forms.Controls/blob/master/TestApp/Pages/CheckboxPages/CheckboxXamlPage.xaml Here you can see how they use, pay attention to the top where it syas xmlns:messier16="clr-namespace:Messier16.Forms.Controls;assembly=Messier16.Forms.Controls" that's what i ment with linking, and you welcome ;)

Comment: Okay I have everything figured out except where to write the Inits? Can you help me with that please? Thanks @JordyDieltjens

Comment: you have to put that in the platform specific code. for android: https://github.com/messier16/Forms.Controls/blob/master/TestApp/Droid/MainActivity.cs  IOS: https://github.com/messier16/Forms.Controls/blob/master/TestApp/iOS/AppDelegate.cs   and UWP: https://github.com/messier16/Forms.Controls/blob/master/TestApp/Uwp/App.xaml.cs just check where u put that line and put it there too, gl

Answer (score 0):

If you want radio buttons you can **xlabs** their package (https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/RadioButton)

I'd just use a picker, Xlabs package hasn't been updated in a while so their might be some bugs in the radiobutton

Comment: But how would I use a picker to achieve my goal of having the user select multiple options?

Comment: Picker doesn't support multiple selection.

Comment: In this scenario i will use a separate content page.

Comment: This answer sounds familiar, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XLabs as suggested by below answer or you can create you own radio buttons with image and set selected and un-selected images on tap of image

i prefer to use my own radio buttons